# using JS event function twice in shiny R to create a dropdown

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny, shinyjs

I'm building a shiny app and one of the things I want to accomplish is to create a dropdown menu. I want to plot the labour variable as a function of the year variable for the different levels. See below for a sample dataframe:

```
  year level_2 level_3 level_4 labour
1  2013      10     101    1011      1
2  2014      10     101    1011      5
3  2015      10     101    1011     10
4  2016      10     101    1011     20
5  2017      10     101    1011     25
6  2013      11     111    1111      5
7  2014      11     111    1111     10
8  2015      11     111    1111     20
9  2016      11     111    1111     25
10 2017      11     111    1111     30
11 2013      10     102    1021      2
12 2014      10     102    1021      6
13 2015      10     102    1021     11
14 2016      10     102    1021     21
15 2017      10     102    1021     26
16 2013      11     112    1122      6
17 2014      11     112    1122     11
18 2015      11     112    1122     21
19 2016      11     112    1122     26
20 2017      11     112    1122     31
```

I already know how to get the first drop down (chart 2 with level_3 is generated by clicking on a specific ime serie from chart 1 level_2). However, I would like to perform a similar action by clicking on a specific time serie from the second highchart (which will be input for a third chart/level_4).

However, I'm kinda stuck. I'm building a webapp By clicking on a time series of the second chart, a third chart should appear. I managed to do this, but the second chart disappears when the third chart is generated. I think it has to do with the fact that the clickevent function overrides the first `input$canvasClicked[[1]]`, but I didn't manage to get the correct result by a) either indexing with `input$canvasClicked[[2]]` or b) creating a second `JS("function(event) { ... }")`.

Any help would be appreciated! Sample code of a simplified app can be found below.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(highcharter)

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    column(width = 4, highchartOutput("hcontainer", height = "500px")),
    column(width = 4, highchartOutput("hcontainer2", height = "500px")),
    column(width = 4, highchartOutput("hcontainer3", height = "500px")) #added add highcharter output
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) { 

  df <- data.frame(year = c(rep(c(2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017), 4)),
                   level_2 = c(rep(c(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11),2)),
                   level_3 = c(101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111,
                               102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112),
                   level_4 = c(c(1011, 1011, 1011, 1011, 1011, 1111, 1111, 1111, 1111, 1111,
                                 1021, 1021, 1021, 1021, 1021, 1122, 1122, 1122, 1122, 1122)), # additional level added
                   labour = c(1, 5, 10, 20, 25, 5, 10, 20, 25, 30,
                              2, 6, 11, 21, 26, 6, 11, 21, 26, 31))

  output$hcontainer <- renderHighchart({ 

    temp <- df %>% 
      group_by(year, level_2) %>% 
      summarize(Sum = sum(labour)) %>% 
      arrange(level_2) 

    hchart(temp, "line", hcaes(x = year, y = Sum, group = level_2)) %>%
      hc_plotOptions(series = list(events = list(click = canvasClickFunction)))

  })

  canvasClickFunction <- JS("function(event) {Shiny.onInputChange('canvasClicked', [this.name, event.point.category]);}")


  #second highcharter which should appear when user clicked on the serie named 10
  output$hcontainer2 <- renderHighchart({ 
    req(input$canvasClicked[[1]])
    temp2 <- df %>% 
      filter(level_2 == input$canvasClicked[[1]]) %>% # filter selected by click
      group_by(year, level_3) %>% 
      summarize(Sum = sum(labour)) %>% 
      arrange(level_3)

    hchart(temp2, "line", hcaes(x = year, y = Sum, group = level_3)) %>%
      hc_title(text = paste0("I clicked ",input$canvasClicked[[1]])) %>% 
      hc_plotOptions(series = list(events = list(click = canvasClickFunction2)))

  })

  canvasClickFunction2 <- JS("function(event) {Shiny.onInputChange('canvasClicked2', [this.name, event.point.category]);}")

    output$hcontainer3 <- renderHighchart({ 
    req(input$canvasClicked2[[1]])

        temp3 <- df %>%
          filter(level_3 == input$canvasClicked2[[1]]) %>% # filter selected by click
          group_by(year, level_4) %>%
          summarize(Sum = sum(labour)) %>%
          arrange(level_4)

        hchart(temp3, "line", hcaes(x = year, y = Sum, group = level_4)) %>% 
          hc_title(text = paste0("I clicked ",input$canvasClicked2[[1]])) #%>%
    })

} 


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: you seems to be binding it twice, which is the `canvasClickFunction` in the second chart, I dont think it should be there at all. Create another `canvasClickFunction2` and bind it to chart 2 `hc_plotOptions`, then use that for chart 3

Comment: @ Pork Chop. Thanks. It is working! I needed to change the `canvasClicked` as well, next to creating a second `canvasClickFunction`. I will update the app above.

Comment: Ok great :)), once you update it please post the answer yourself and accept it for reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Pork Chop, the app is working. I needed to change the `canvasClicked` part in the new `JS("function(event) { ... }")` to get the app working. The sample code now looks like:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(highcharter)

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    column(width = 4, highchartOutput("hcontainer", height = "500px")),
    column(width = 4, highchartOutput("hcontainer2", height = "500px")),
    column(width = 4, highchartOutput("hcontainer3", height = "500px")) #added add highcharter output
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) { 

  df <- data.frame(year = c(rep(c(2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017), 4)),
                   level_2 = c(rep(c(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11),2)),
                   level_3 = c(101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111,
                               102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112),
                   level_4 = c(c(1011, 1011, 1011, 1011, 1011, 1111, 1111, 1111, 1111, 1111,
                                 1021, 1021, 1021, 1021, 1021, 1122, 1122, 1122, 1122, 1122)), # additional level added
                   labour = c(1, 5, 10, 20, 25, 5, 10, 20, 25, 30,
                              2, 6, 11, 21, 26, 6, 11, 21, 26, 31))

  output$hcontainer <- renderHighchart({ 

    temp <- df %>% 
      group_by(year, level_2) %>% 
      summarize(Sum = sum(labour)) %>% 
      arrange(level_2) 

    hchart(temp, "line", hcaes(x = year, y = Sum, group = level_2)) %>%
      hc_plotOptions(series = list(events = list(click = canvasClickFunction)))

  })

  canvasClickFunction <- JS("function(event) {Shiny.onInputChange('canvasClicked', [this.name, event.point.category]);}")


  #second highcharter which should appear when user clicked on the serie named 10
  output$hcontainer2 <- renderHighchart({ 
    req(input$canvasClicked[[1]])
    temp2 <- df %>% 
      filter(level_2 == input$canvasClicked[[1]]) %>% # filter selected by click
      group_by(year, level_3) %>% 
      summarize(Sum = sum(labour)) %>% 
      arrange(level_3)

    hchart(temp2, "line", hcaes(x = year, y = Sum, group = level_3)) %>%
      hc_title(text = paste0("I clicked ",input$canvasClicked[[1]])) %>% 
      hc_plotOptions(series = list(events = list(click = canvasClickFunction2)))

  })

  canvasClickFunction2 <- JS("function(event) {Shiny.onInputChange('canvasClicked2', [this.name, event.point.category]);}")

    output$hcontainer3 <- renderHighchart({ 
    req(input$canvasClicked2[[1]])

        temp3 <- df %>%
          filter(level_3 == input$canvasClicked2[[1]]) %>% # filter selected by click
          group_by(year, level_4) %>%
          summarize(Sum = sum(labour)) %>%
          arrange(level_4)

        hchart(temp3, "line", hcaes(x = year, y = Sum, group = level_4)) %>% 
          hc_title(text = paste0("I clicked ",input$canvasClicked2[[1]])) #%>%
    })

} 


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I will accept the answer for reference once i'm able to (after two days).